# How to get SpeechRecognizer listner response in js function?

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I am working on SpeechRecognizer Listner activity.

I am triggering the intent (startListning(intent)) from Webview button click threw javascript

```
act.startFun();
```

And the startFun() method is declared in my MainActivity.java file

```
public void startFun(){
        Log.d(TAG,"ONCLICK");
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);         
 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
         intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");
         intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5); 
         sr.startListening(intent);
   }
```

and my SpeechRecognizer Listner is like

```
class listner implements RecognitionListener{  
            public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            end=1;
            Log.d(TAG, "onResults");
        }

        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRmsChanged");
        }
    }
```

My requirement is i want to pass the onResults(Bundle results) 's result string to my javascript method.

Please some one help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to pass a variable to a JavaScript function... but you could
create a class JavaScriptInterface and signal the JavaScript to get the string when you have it ready.

```
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(),"Interface");
```

list the functions you want to call in the JavaScriptInterface class.
Then in your javascript...

```
Interface.getStringResult();
```

You can also create a function to check to see if the interface exists in JavaScript:

```
function runningInAndroidApp() {
    if (typeof Interface != 'undefined') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Joel thanks for your reply. Already i aware of this. see my post i have posted the code act.startFun() - which "act" is the javascript interface only.

Comment: My requirement is say var response = Interface.init(). init will invoke the speechRecognization and i need an response of onResult() method in Speech Listner from the init() method itself

Comment: your requirements now seem a bit ambiguous to me.. but the only way to  send data to your javascript is by returning a primitive datatype (or String) in one of these interfaces. You could do a loadUrl() to call a javascript function, but you cannot pass it any arguments.