# SpeechRecognizer - time limit

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am using [SppechRecognizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) for voice recognizer application. Its working fine. My requirement is i want to stop the voice listening after 1 sec or 2 sec. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 or 2 seconds doesn't seem to be a lot of time but if you want to set a time limit, you'd probably have to thread it. Android has some default extras to set the minimum length of speech input and maximum amount after a user has stopped speaking, but none to set the maximum length of time for speech input.

Your best bet would be to thread some sort of timer, something like a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
 yourSpeechListener.startListening(yourRecognizerIntent);
 new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         //do nothing, just let it tick
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         yourSpeechListener.stopListening();
     }
  }.start();
```

I would also encourage you to look at the extras available for the [RecognizerIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS) to see if there's anything more suitable to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Otra. This is the exact scenario i need. I hope you can help me on this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105937/how-to-get-speechrecognizer-listner-response-in-js-function/