# Get URI of saved audio in OnResults(Bundle result) in Speech RecognitionListener android

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition, recognizer-intent

I followed almost everylink for audio saving and converting it to text but I did not find any way that how I can get audio Url in custom Recognition Listener

1. [record/save audio from voice recognition intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047433/record-save-audio-from-voice-recognition-intent/23070879#23070879)
2. [How to use Androids' speech to text with audio sample file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849379/how-to-use-androids-speech-to-text-with-audio-sample-file)

and many others as welll....
Audio url that I got here with the help of RecognizerIntent

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                    Uri audioUri = data.getData();
                    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
                    try {
                        InputStream filestream = contentResolver.openInputStream(audioUri);
                        copyInputStreamToFile(filestream, new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/recording.amr"));
                        Log.e("audio", "uri= "+ audioUri);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

I want to get it here because I dont want to use Google dialog I want to customize it without dialog

```
 @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        String str = new String();
        Log.d("testing1", "onResults " + results);
        data = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);

        str=data.get(0)+"";
        result_txt.setText(str);
        speech.stopListening();

        if(speech!=null){
            speech.destroy();
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to get URL from this bundle results. 
I have two queries:

- Please let me know Hoe can I achieve audio saved URI in bundles
- When I Customized Speech to Text It listens for a long time Just like RecognitionIntent if audio is not recording in 2-3 seconds it says did nt find any sound Same thing I want to do it with customized one as it listens for a long time.
  I followed these links for second qestion:
- [Android - Speech Recognition Limiting Listening Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868054/android-speech-recognition-limiting-listening-time)
- [Voice Recognition stops listening after a few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670378/voice-recognition-stops-listening-after-a-few-seconds)

and many others as well. 
Its not the duplicate question people have already asked this question but solution given to them is using

> startActivityForResult

and then get the audio url in above mentioned snippet of code but i want to get it in

> onResults(Bundle results)

Please ask me if any doubt is there. I want to use it in fragment.
Thanks in advance!!.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I need .amr file from onResult method. and i m getting solution from no where.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: no answer so far I used in other manner then

Comment: I am also looking for same. Any help ??

Comment: did anybody got solution? i am also searching

Comment: no solutions so far

Comment: anybody solved this issue???

Comment: did anyone has a solution for this? same issue here.