# How can i get audio URI from onResults method of RecognitionListener interface in android?

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition

I am looking each and everywhere on Web for getting URI of audio file from RecognitionListener, Using listener I am getting text what i speak as an output. But I am not able to get URI of audio. I have not found any other link rather than this - [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38759020/2702583) which is still unanswered. If anyone knows how to achieve this?

```html
@Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        Log.i("Voice Recognition", "onResults");
        ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        txtOutput.setText(matches.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to ask the same question again, instead you can assign a bounty on the question you have interest in.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resuleCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resuleCode, intent);

        if (resuleCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == INTENT_PICK_AUDIO) {
                Uri uri = intent.getData(); }}
```

Comment: I know this way. But this solution will Show Google Default Dialog like "speak now". I don't want to show that dialog on my screen.