# Get audio from voice recognition intent

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, recognizer-intent

I followed almost every link for getting audio data in `onActivityResult()` of `RecognizerIntent`.

[1. Get URI of saved audio in OnResults(Bundle result) in Speech RecognitionListener android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759020/get-uri-of-saved-audio-in-onresultsbundle-result-in-speech-recognitionlistener)

[2. record/save audio from voice recognition intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047433/record-save-audio-from-voice-recognition-intent)

I follow the same approach, and my code is almost identical. But I am getting a **null** back from `data.getData()`;
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    String language = Locale.US.toString();
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, language);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language);

    intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO_FORMAT", "audio/AMR");
    intent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.GET_AUDIO", true);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();

        // This part works fine.
        ArrayList<String> matches = bundle.getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        // But audioUri is always null !!!
        Uri audioUri = data.getData();
        ...
}
```

And in my AndroidManifest.xml file, I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which activity does the RecognizerIntent resolve to? Does the recording attachment work in Google Keep?

Comment: Thanks for responding.The startVoiceRecognitionActivity() method that creates a RecognizerIntent  is invoked upon a menu button click. The recording attachment does work in Google Keep.

Comment: Every activity belongs to an app. My question was to find out which app it is (incl. a version number). (But if the same recognizer app works together with Google Keep, then I'm out of ideas.)